# Refused to display google in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I was wondering to make something for fun like website with look of desktop and files, folders...
When I try to make a "web browser" I need iframe for displaying the page inside iframe.
But pages like google.com,  facebook.com, twitter.com, youtube.com dooesn't allow this.
Is there way to manage trough it or it is disabled in any way?
I know it is made for security reasons but why would this what I need damage the site up?

```
I tried with javascript: load() and php print file_get_contents()
```

Load doesnt work and php just copy paste the page content...

Answer (score 0):

There is not workaround as it's for security reason, this is done to prevent clickjacking (also called a "UI redress" attack). In a clickjacking attack, the page displays a click-activated component of another site inside an `<iframe>` and tricks the user into clicking it (usually by layering the the target component on top of an apparently-clickable feature of the framing site).

[Reference link 1](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/67889/why-do-browsers-enforce-the-same-origin-security-policy-on-iframes)

[Reference link 2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)

Comment: SO I guess it is not possible.

Comment: what about in flash ?